# Do the 'int' objects in Python only contain values?

Tags: python, class, object, int

Let's take the following Python code:

```
a = 3
print(a)
```

As far as I know, *a* is a reference to an object of class *int* — correct me if I am wrong. Diagrammatically, it should look something like this, *as far as I know*.

```
    The object of 'int' class
       containing value 3

        |---|
a ----> | 3 |
        |---|
```

Does the 'int' object in memory only contain the value 3 or it contains some space for other variables as well?

Our professor told us that it looks something like below:

```
   The object of class 'int'
        |--------|
        |   ___  |
a ----> |   |3|  |
        |   ---  |
        |--------|
```

So, is the remaining space utilized by some other variables?

Comment: Using `sys.getsizeof()` to check the size 3 has a size of 28 bytes. So yes, there is other information contained within the int object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object in Python inherits from the `object` class, which means that it's treated as any Python object, not as a primitive value as you'd expect from a language like C. This is what people mean when they say that *in Python, everything is an object*.

For example, the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)  class has a method `__str__` that dictates what its string representation looks like:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> a.__str__()
'3'
```

You can use `dir(a)` to get a list of every method associated with `a`.

So to answer your question, yes - the `int` object does not only allocates the space needed for the primitive value itself, but also for the whole Python object associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the *to the point* answer. But then how does *a* accesses the primitive value — in this case, 3. This is far different from *pointers* in C because the object is referenced by *a* and not the primitive value itself. Is the primitive value present at the base memory location from where the int object starts consuming memory which makes it easier to access?

Comment: All instances consist of a pointer to their type and a reference count. There is some additional bookkeeping info whose details I don't recall, as well as space required for the actual value. 0, for instance, is 24 bytes on a 64-bit machine. Numbers with an absolute value under 2**30 require an additional 4 bytes, and the size grows in 4-byte increments as the magnitude of the number requires.

Comment: @NirajRaut By design, the primitive value is "kept away" from the Python user. From a C standpoint, all objects in Python are structs named `PyObject` whose value you can't (normally) access directly. So `a` is really a reference to the `PyObject`, not its value. This link may help clarify this further: https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/.

Comment: (And most of *this* is specific to the CPython implementation of the Python language. Python itself doesn't expose how an object is actually structured in memory.)

Comment: @NirajRaut  Yes, and note, Python doesn't used fixed-size primitive int types, but rather, arbitrary length int objects. Essentially, in the PyObject struct there is a pointer to a primitive array to hold the raw bytes necessary to encode integers of arbitrary size. Here is a pretty decent blog post: https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/how-python-implements-super-long-integers-12icwon5vk

Comment: @chepner: No extra bookkeeping info is needed for integers; what you listed is everything. On a typical 64-bit machine an int object has an 8-byte type pointer, an 8-byte reference count, an 8-byte combination limb count + sign, and 4 bytes per 30-bit limb, and that's all. For objects that need to be tracked by the cyclic garbage collector (e.g., lists) there _is_ additional bookkeeping needed, but an int can never be involved in a reference cycle, so that extra overhead doesn't apply.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah, thanks. I would count the need for a limb count and explicit sign as "bookkeeping", but I wasn't entirely sure how, exactly, the bits of the actual data were stored. (I was thinking it was simply an array of words, and couldn't quite square up why a non-zero value added 8 bytes, but then only grew 4 bytes at a time as the number grew larger.)

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose those do count as bookkeeping. Fair enough. Incidentally, the 4-byte increments reported by `sys.getsizeof` are a little bit bogus, since CPython's small object allocator only ever allocates space in multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Hey, this is not at all related but please tell me the difference between an ```instance``` and an ```object```?

Comment: @NirajRaut: No real difference; the two terms are used more-or-less interchangeably, at least in Python 3. (In Python 2, and especially pre Python 2.2, the story was a bit more complicated, but that's ancient history now.) There are some subtle nuances here, but nothing substantial.

Comment: Like you said, not related. Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759099/difference-between-object-and-instance-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking but you can use `type()` to check what class an object or variable is:

```
type(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.