# TypeError: setSubregion_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subregion_id'

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Build Pattern project. I'm not sure why I have this error:

```
TypeError: setSubregion_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'subregion_id'
```

```
    from enum import Enum, unique
     
    @unique
    class Subregions(Enum):
     
        PL002 = 1
        PL002 = 2
```

```
    class InstanceBuilder(object):
     
        def __init__(self):
           
            self.subregion_id = Subregions()
            
     
        def getSubregion_id(self):
            return self.subregion_id
     
        def setSubregion_id(self, subregion_id):
            subregion_id = Subregions()
            return subregion_id
```

```
class Instance():
 
    def __init__(self, subregion_id ):
         
        self.subregion_id = subregion_id
```

```
from Builder.InstanceBuilder import InstanceBuilder
from Builder.Subregions import Subregions
 
def main():
 
    instance = InstanceBuilder.setSubregion_id(Subregions.PL001).build
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: it shows me also problem i class Instance(). How can I call to value in Subregions in constructor?

Comment: Like  in my answer, try changing `instance = InstanceBuilder.setSubregion_id(Subregions.PL001).build` to `instance = InstanceBuilder.setSubregion_id(InstanceBuilder(), Subregions.PL001).build`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `InstanceBuilder.setSubregion_id`, you using it as an unbound method, so it will not be able to access the attributes defined in the `__init__` function, unless you already have a class object defined so you can pass it in as the `self` parameter.

But that wouldn't make sense, because if you already have the class object defined, you can simple do

```
class_object = InstanceBuilde()
class_object.setSubregion_id(Subregions.PL001).build`
```

instead of

```
class_object = InstanceBuilde()
InstanceBuilder.setSubregion_id(class_object, Subregions.PL001).build
```

**So basically**, because you are using the function as an unbound method, **python takes the `Subregions.PL001` you passed into the brackets as the `self` argument, hence it thinks that it's the `subregion_id` argument that's missing**.

```
def main():
    instance = InstanceBuilder.setSubregion_id(Subregions.PL001).build
```

to

```
def main():
    instance = InstanceBuilder().setSubregion_id(Subregions.PL001).build
```

Read the differences between an unbound method and a bound method here:
[Objects vs instance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368432/objects-vs-instance-in-python)

Comment: I need to have acces in method setSubregion_id to values in class Subregions. And I'm not sure how this method should looks like.

Comment: @roganjosh Oh, sorry about that! I hope I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def main():
    instanceBuilder = InstanceBuilder()
    instance = instanceBuilder.setSubregion_id(Subregions.PL001).build
```